# jquery selector for error class generated in jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am working with jquery validation which is when press the submit button show error icon after hover the error icon message will display in tooltip. validation working fine with error icon now I want tool tip

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    rules:{firstname:"required"},
    messages:{firstname:"<div class='fir' style='display:none'>Please  enter your firstname</div>"
    }
});
```

I am trying to calling hover function it is not working

```
$('.error').hover(function(){
        alert("hello");
    });
```

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: try using `on()` and `mouseover` together mate.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the elements are created by the validation framework, they are dynamic so you need to make use of event delegation

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".error", function () {
    //stuff to do on mouseover
})
```

Comment: $(document).on("mouseenter", "label .error", function () {
            $('.fir').show();
         });    why it is not working

Comment: I think it should be `$(document).on("mouseenter", "label.error", function () { $('.fir').show(); });`, no space between `label` and `.error`

Comment: @downvoter did you downvote me and the upvote all the wrong answers below!!! I didn't downvote them anyway... common man.... don't be that idiot

Comment: arun i have one problem in validation when i press sumbit button error icon display after input filed .but in the case of onkeyup the error icon display in next line starting  i want after input filed

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong function, try this:

```
$('.error').mouseover(function(){
                alert("hello");
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for help but i am sorry to say that it is not working  i tried mouseover and mouseenter,hover funtion is not calling

Comment: Yeah, but this is the correct function that I've used a lot of time. So now you need to check your class .error(displaying) or make sure you have this class in your element class="error" for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate.Hope this might help u .. :)

```
$(".error").on("mouseover", function () {
    //stuff to do on mouseover
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (put your code in document ready function...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.error').mouseover(function(){
                alert("hello");
            });           
 });
```

[REFERENCE MOUSEOVER](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)